How to measure the length of the last line? (LuaLaTeX)
I would like to make a command which, like some environments for equations, has a vertical space at the start of it which depends on whether the length of the line in the previous paragraph exceeds a certain value (long line) or not (short line). Even though this isn't a command for displaying mathematical content, I know it's possible to use the \the\predisplaysize length, but it's not very practical to use.
I was wondering if it was possible, using LuaLaTeX, to create a \measureLastLineWidth command which could measure the length of the last line and store that length in \lastLineWidth so that it could be reused in another command?
If the previous line is not a line of "text", for example a table, an image, a float, etc, then \lastLineWidth should be equal to 0pt.
I don't really know much about LuaLaTeX as such although I use it regularly, but I do know that it's a powerful tool that can probably do this sort of thing with callbacks.
Here is a test file:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum, mwe}

\newlength{\lastLineWidth}
\newcommand{\measureLastLineWidth}{}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\measureLastLineWidth

\the\lastLineWidth

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-16x9}
\end{figure}

\measureLastLineWidth
\the\lastLineWidth% Here, \the\lastLineWidth should be equal to 0pt, because it is following a float in the output file.

\lipsum[2]
\measureLastLineWidth

\the\lastLineWidth

\lipsum[3]
\measureLastLineWidth

\the\lastLineWidth

\includegraphics{example-image-16x9}

\measureLastLineWidth
\the\lastLineWidth% Here, \the\lastLineWidth should be equal to 0pt, because it is following an image in the output file.

\lipsum[4]
\measureLastLineWidth

\the\lastLineWidth

\lipsum[1]

\measureLastLineWidth
\the\lastLineWidth

\lipsum[2]

\measureLastLineWidth
\the\lastLineWidth
\end{document}


See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/716681/264024

You can use a similar approach to the one in this answer. The measuring is done automatically, you can disable and enable it with \dontmeasureLastLineWidth, and \measureLastLineWidth.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum, mwe}

\newdimen\lastLineWidth
\directlua{
 local disabled = false
 local function lastline_length(head,c)
    if disabled then 
        return head
    end
    local last_line = node.tail(head)
    local parfill_node
    for n in node.traverse_id(node.id('glue'),last_line.list) do
        if n.subtype == 15 then parfill_node = n end 
    end
    local length, _, _ = node.rangedimensions(last_line,last_line.head,parfill_node)
    tex.setdimen('global', 'lastLineWidth',length)
    return head
 end
 local measureLastLineWidth = luatexbase.new_luafunction"measureLastLineWidth"
 lua.get_functions_table()[measureLastLineWidth] = function() disabled = false end
 token.set_lua("measureLastLineWidth", measureLastLineWidth, "protected")
 local dontmeasureLastLineWidth = luatexbase.new_luafunction"dontmeasureLastLineWidth"
 lua.get_functions_table()[dontmeasureLastLineWidth] = function() disabled = true 
    tex.setdimen('global', 'lastLineWidth',0)   end
 token.set_lua("dontmeasureLastLineWidth", dontmeasureLastLineWidth, "protected")
 luatexbase.add_to_callback('post_linebreak_filter',lastline_length,'lastline')
}

\AddToHook{env/figure/before}{\dontmeasureLastLineWidth}
\AddToHook{env/figure/after}{\measureLastLineWidth}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\the\lastLineWidth

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-16x9}
\end{figure}

\the\lastLineWidth% Here, \the\lastLineWidth should be equal to 0pt, because it is following a float in the output file.

\lipsum[2]

\the\lastLineWidth

\lipsum[3]

\the\lastLineWidth

\dontmeasureLastLineWidth
\includegraphics{example-image-16x9}
\par\measureLastLineWidth

\the\lastLineWidth% Here, \the\lastLineWidth should be equal to 0pt, because it is following an image in the output file.

\lipsum[4]

\the\lastLineWidth

\lipsum[1]

\the\lastLineWidth

\lipsum[2]

\the\lastLineWidth
\end{document}

